# Trying to connect to MySQL via PHP, Database connection failed: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, osx-mavericks, symlink

I upgraded my laptop from OS X 10.7.5 to 10.9.2 yesterday. It seemed like there was no MySQL installed so I went ahead and installed it. However, my phpMyAdmin was still not working so I tried a bunch of online solutions including creating symbolic links to the mysql socket. I think I have overdone some of the steps and in the wrong way. phpMyAdmin still doesn't work and when I run a PHP script to connect to MySQL I get the error "Database connection failed: Too many levels of symbolic links". I reinstalled MySQL and set php.ini to default after I encountered this problem but nothing changed.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you created a loop with those links you created. I suggest you check those links and where they point to. It should be possible to fix that...

Comment: That turned out to be case, thanks for the advice! I found the file which seemed to be linking to itself eventually and deleted it. Then there was still the initial problem of not finding the socket. So I put the appropriate directory ("/tmp/mysql.socket") for default_socket in both php.ini and config.inc.php (and also changed config.inc.php to have socket for connect_type) and now it works!

Comment: You are welcome. This is the obvious cause if you get such an error message.